# Pandas Groupby operation on a large dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a large dataset expanding > 50 years. Each year has ~10 million lines of records with multiple variables/columns. I need to perform groupby operations by location and time. My code runs extremely slow - it takes 2-5 hours to process 1 year's data depending on the number of stations in the year. I looked at a few posts on multiprocessing, but since I have no experiences with it, I am not sure if that method applies to my problem. I'd appreciate it if someone can point out how I can make the code more efficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import argparse
from scipy.stats.mstats import hmean

def Nstat(df):
    duMW = [6,7,8,9,30,31,32,33,34,35,98]
    d = {}
    d['NMW']  = df['MW'].count()
    d['NPW']  = df['PW'].count()
    d['NDU']  = df.loc[ isd['RH']<=90,'MW'].isin(duMW).sum()
    d['NDU6']  = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==6 ).sum()
    d['NDU7']  = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==7 ).sum()
    d['NDU8']  = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==8 ).sum()
    d['NDU9']  = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==9 ).sum()
    d['NDU30'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==30).sum()
    d['NDU31'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==31).sum()
    d['NDU32'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==32).sum()
    d['NDU33'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==33).sum()
    d['NDU34'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==34).sum()
    d['NDU35'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==35).sum()
    d['NDU98'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==98).sum()
    d['NDUpw'] = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'PW']==3).sum()
    d['VIS_Hvg'] = hmean(df.loc[df['VIS']>0,'VIS'])
    d['Vi_Avg'] = df['Vi'].mean()

    return pd.Series(d,index=['NMW','NPW',\
'NDU','NDU6','NDU7','NDU8','NDU9','NDU30','NDU31','NDU32',\
'NDU33','NDU34','NDU35','NDU98','NDUpw','VIS_Hvg','Vi_Avg'])


if __name__ =='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("start_year",type=int,help='4-digit start year')
    parser.add_argument("end_year",type=int,help='4-digit end year')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    years = np.arange(args.start_year,args.end_year)

    dTypes = {
        'NMW':'Int32',\
        'NPW':'Int32',\
        'NDU':'Int32',\
        'NDU6':'Int32',\
        'NDU7':'Int32',\
        'NDU8':'Int32',\
        'NDU9':'Int32',\
        'NDU30':'Int32',\
        'NDU31':'Int32',\
        'NDU32':'Int32',\
        'NDU33':'Int32',\
        'NDU34':'Int32',\
        'NDU35':'Int32',\
        'NDU98':'Int32',\
        'NDUpw':'Int32'\
    }

    for iyr,yr in enumerate(years):
        print('process year {:d} at {:s}'.format(yr,datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
        isd = pd.read_hdf('isd_lite_'+str(yr)+'.h5',dtype={'STATION':'str'})

        isd['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(isd['YYYYMMDDHH'],format='%Y%m%d%H').dt.strftime('%Y%m')
        isd['VIS'] = isd['VIS']/1000.
        isd['Vi'] = isd['VIS'].apply(lambda x: 1/x if x>0 else np.nan)

        print('>> groupby and output at {:s}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

        stn_month = isd.groupby(['STATION','YYYYMM']).apply(Nstat).reset_index().astype(dTypes)
        stn_month.to_csv('stn_month_'+str(yr)+'.csv',index=False,float_format='%.3f')
```

The last groupby (by STATION and YYYYMM) operation is most time consuming.
I have a fairly good work station (256 cores) and want to maximize the use of it.

A sample file is provided [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJN7dYYpcG73PSJOB8zukAR14FnfZt_e/view?usp=sharing). It takes 7 min to process this file. Not horribly long due to a small number of stations.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please state a bit more about the goal of your program, perhaps read the [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) to get the most out of your question.

Comment: Have you considered [using other libraries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html#use-other-libraries) besides or in addition to pandas, like [Dask](https://dask.org/)?  It has parallel versions of `.groupby` and can be set up to use multiple cores or computers.

Comment: @Juho sample file is provided. It takes ~7 minutes to process this file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJN7dYYpcG73PSJOB8zukAR14FnfZt_e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Juho sorry about that. code fixed. should work now.

Comment: @Juho use `python script.py 1947 1948` to run for 1947 only. It will take <7 minutes on your end, since I removed some lines. The last groupby is what I am trying to optimize.

Comment: Running your code with the mentioned arguments gives me `KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107191/discussion-between-xin-and-juho).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following points:

1. Pandas has a good datetime functionality; you shouldn't cast into strings and then later on group by those. It's unnatural and slow. Instead, just do:

   ```
   isd['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(isd['YYYYMMDDHH'],format='%Y%m%d%H')
   ```

   And then in the groupby, you can simply do

   ```
   stn_month = isd.groupby(['STATION', isd['YYYYMM'].dt.to_period('M')]) ...
   ```
2. In general, using `apply` is usually not great for performance. First, notice that you are doing a lot of things inside `Nstat` that are not necessary: all the lines like `d['NDU6']  = (df.loc[ df['RH']<=90,'MW']==6 ).sum()` are unnecessary in a sense that you can just precompute this outside of the function. As a side note, the way that you write is unnatural to me and I would more simply do:

   ```
   df[(df['RH'] <= 90) & (df['MW'] == 6)]
   ```

   Second, the `agg` function also takes a dictionary so that you can just do:

   ```
   isd.groupby(['STATION', isd['YYYYMM'].dt.to_period('M')]).agg({'MW' : 'count', 'PW' : 'count', 'Vi': 'mean'})
   ```

   I hope this will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my script had an error, hence the ridiculously long runtime. After fixing the error, runtime is shortened, but the code itself is still inefficient. The real problem is in `Nstat` - The row-based computation is both CPU and memory-inefficient. For those interested, [read this](https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/).

Thanks to @Juho, I removed `Nstat` and switched to agg. Runtime is reduced by more than half!

```
        #prescreening by RH>90%
        isd.loc[ isd.RH>90, 'MW'] = 0
        isd.loc[ isd.RH>90, 'PW'] = 0

        stn_month = isd.groupby(['STATION',isd.DATE.dt.to_period('M')]).agg(
            NMW=('MW','count'),\
            NPW=('PW','count'),\
            NDU=('MW',lambda x: x.isin(duMW).sum()),\
            NDU6=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(6).sum()),\
            NDU7=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(7).sum()),\
            NDU8=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(8).sum()),\
            NDU9=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(9).sum()),\
            NDU30=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(30).sum()),\
            NDU31=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(31).sum()),\
            NDU32=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(32).sum()),\
            NDU33=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(33).sum()),\
            NDU34=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(34).sum()),\
            NDU35=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(35).sum()),\
            NDU98=('MW',lambda x: x.eq(98).sum()),\
            NDUPW=('PW',lambda x: x.eq(3).sum()),\
            VIS=('VIS',lambda x: hmean(x[x>0])),\
            Vi=('Vi','mean'),\
            DUP=('DUP','mean')\
            ).reset_index().astype(dTypes)

stn_month.to_csv('../stat/yearly/stn_all/stn_month_{:d}.csv'.format(yr),index=False,float_format='%.3f')
```

Comment: Great to see such an improvement!